find a non trivial Lie transformation group for $y'-(1-x)y^2-y=0$
I'm trying to find a nontrivial Lie transformation group admitted by the ODE $$y'-(1-x)y^2-y=0  \text{.}$$
As a hint, the exercise suggests that we consider the generator $$X = (ax+by)\partial_x+(cy+dxy+exy^2+fx^2y^2)\partial_y$$
with $a,b,c,d,e,f$ constants to be determined.
I tried the following: Call $\xi(x,y)=ax+by$, $\eta(x,y)=cy+dxy+exy^2+fx^2y^2$ and $g(x,y)=(1-x)y^2+y$. If $X$ is the generator of the transformation we are looking for, then the determining equation $$\eta_x+(\eta_y-\xi_x)g-\xi_yg^2-\xi g_x-\eta g_y=0$$ holds. Substituting in the ecuation and comparing term to term takes us to the system $$-a+d=0\\ -a-b-c+e=0\\ 2a+c-d+e+2f=0 \\d+f=0\\b=0$$
with solution $a=k,b=0,c=0,d=k,e=k,f=-k$. The problem now is that $$\eta(x,y)=\xi(x,y)g(x,y)$$ for any value of $k$, which means that the transformation group is trivial. How I am supposed to find a non trivial one?

$y'-(1-x)y^2-y=0\quad$ is a Riccati ODE which general solution is $\quad y(x)=\frac{1}{x-2+c:e^{-x}}\quad$.

Change of function $y(x)=\frac{1}{u(x)} \quad\implies\quad u'+u+1-x=0 \quad\implies\quad u(x)=x-2+c,e^{-x}$ gives the solution.
